# Simulation of time series from pdf function, defined for each time step, with aucorrelation

Tags: time-series, autocorrelation, simulation

I have a model defined by $\mathbf{X}= (X_{1}, X_{2},... X_{t} ... X_{M})$, where for each $t$ (time step) $X_{t}$ follow a distribution ${D(\alpha_{t}, \beta_{t} )}$.

I want to generate time series from these distributions. The first thing I tried was a simple sampling, meaning that: 1) I (matlab) generated random probabilities $p_{t}$ from a uniform distribution ($U(0,1)$), 2) I have the cdf $F_{t} $of ${D(\alpha_{t}, \beta_{t} )}$ for each time step, then I found $\hat{y}_{t} = F^{-1}_{t}(p_{t})$, 3) I constructed one time series $\hat{Y^{(1)}}$ and 4) I repeated this process 100 times (then I had 100 time series, $\hat{Y^{(k)}}, k\in[1,100]$)

The problem is that my "true" time series $Y$ is autocorrelated until the lag 3, and that each simulated time series $\hat{Y^{(k)}}$ did not display temporal structure at all (no autocorrelation). How could I solve this kind of thing ? I am not familiar with the AR models or MCMC simulations so anyone have an idea in which direction should I start with ?

Many thanks !!

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by "solve this kind of thing"? The situation you present is one in which your model does not account for an important feature of the data. If you are asking how to model your data, you will need to describe those data and the purpose of the model.  Otherwise, what are you asking?

Comment: yes, my model does not account for the autocorrelation or too weakly but is fairly good on other aspects. I was wondering if, without modifying the model, it was possible to add more "constraints" in the simulation process in order to consider the autocorrelation.

Comment: It depends on the distribution as well as the data.  (For some distributions autocorrelation would be a poor description of dependence; for others, there are natural ways to include autocorrelation and they tend to work well.) You might want to share some details of the data and you model.

Comment: My distributions at each time step follow a two-parameter Gamma law and my true time series is like daily precipitation amount (with lot of zero ). Thanks for your help

Comment: I find it hard to reconcile those two statements, because a Gamma law is not consistent with large numbers of zeros.